How do I find all the built-in functions and reserved keywords in Python code?
I need to use Python to identify all the built-in functions and reserved keywords in a piece of Python code.
A list of them can be found in this StackOverflow answer.
Example input: from django.utils.module_loading import import_string
Output: [0,4], [33,39]
How can this be accomplished?

What is your question? You already have the answer from the link you posted.
